# calling javascript function from java function(cordovaActivity) android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I am new to android and am developing the app using cordova.In the meanwhile I am forced to switch between native and angularjs and the good thing is am able to call java method from javascript code but i can't achieve the reverse.This is my android code

```
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{

 JavaScriptInterface javaScriptToJava = new JavaScriptInterface(this);


 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.init();

appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
appView.addJavascriptInterface(javaScriptToJava, "javaScriptToJava");
// Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
loadUrl(launchUrl);
}

//on ActivityResult method
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent){

if (requestCode == 0) {
    Log.d("outside","on ----------------------");
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //get the extras that are returned from the intent
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        Log.d("inside on activity result",contents);


    }
}

if(requestCode==1)
{
    Log.d("onactivity result","got into second activity");
        int position=intent.getIntExtra("Message",0);
        Log.d("inside on activity result",""+position);
           //appView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javaScriptToJava.startScanner())");

        //this is working-----------
        //appView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('signin').click()})()");


        //appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        appView.loadUrl("javascript:testFunction()");   


}

}
}
```

I have two activities, on the onActivityResult I wanna call javascript function but am getting testFunction() is not defined and this line is working fine

```
<ion-view style="background: #8eb4e3;" >

<ion-content has-header="false"
padding="true">
<div class="body" >
    <div style="margin-top: 60px;" align="center">
        <img src="img/login_logo_MyStock.png" class="loginLogo">
            </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 25px;" align="center" ng-enter="login1()"  >
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;" align="center">
        <img src="img/Tesco.png" class="tescoLogo">
            </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("inside script");
   function testFunction()
   {
    alert("came to testFunction");        
   }
 </script>
 </ion-content>

 </ion-view>
```

Can anyone help on this issue???

Comment: appView.loadUrl("javascript:testFunction()");   should work

Comment: @jcesarmobile its coming as testFunction() is not defined,,,is there any problem in placing the script inside ion-content???

Comment: I have no idea about ionic, but try putting the js code inside the head tag